# Global hotkey that send keystroke to another app

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator, shortcut

I want to configure a global hotkey like F5, and when I press F5 it should send [Command]+[Option]+[Control]+[Up Arrow] to the Skype app.

Anyone knows an app that I can do this, or script.

Answer (score 3):

BetterTouchTool can do this. So can Keyboard Maestro but that would really be overkill.

Comment: +1 It is possible with Better Touch, fairly simple to do actually. Did not tried  Keyboard maestro tho.

Answer (score 1):

Write an AppleScript to do what you want.

Then:

Configure it as a Service using Automator, and assign a keyboard shortcut to it via the Keyboard System Prefs.

**Or**

Get a copy of [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) and assign the keyboard shortcut using that.